# method XXX is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a strange issue. I use Unity as IOC/DI. I want to create instance of class LoggerService, but the error appers **'LoggerService.LogException(System.Exception, string, string)' is inaccessible due to its protection level'**. I have a few classes used by Unity which internal access modifier (no access modifier for class), and thay are accessible in code. Why it not working here?

My code is following:

```
//console app executable module:
 static void CommonOnUnhandledException(Exception exception, string messagePrefix) 
        {
            var logger = Ioc.Resolve<LoggerService>(Config);
            logger.LogException(exception, String.Empty, String.Empty);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} unhandled exception: {1}; {2}", messagePrefix, exception.Message, exception.StackTrace));
        }

//library Services.dll
class LoggerService : ILoggerService 
    {


        public LoggerService(AppConfiguration configuration)
        {
            ...
         }
        public void LogException(Exception ex, string url = "", string messageContent = "")
        {
...

        }
}

//library services dll, started in console app
 public static class ServicesModule
    {
        public static void Init(UnityContainer container)
        {
            // register all other ordinary types:
            container.RegisterType<IIntelShopService, IntelShopService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IBackendService, BackendService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IIntelODataService, IntelODataService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<ILoggerService, Log4NetLoggerService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IPerformanceTrackerService, PerformanceTrackerService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        }
    }
```

Comment: LoggerService is internal by default and will be accessible only inside the dll.

Comment: IM asking about problem with IOC, not the solution without IOC!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to resolve `ILoggerService` instead of a specific implementation.

If you resolve concrete types instead of interfaces, you're using only half of the power of unity or dependency injection/inversion of control in general.

BTW: the implementations *should* most of the time be `internal`, while interfaces on the other hand tend to be `public`.

Comment: This is what I found yesterday too ;).

Answer (score 2):

You have to make your class `public`. It's useful to always use a modificator for methods, properties and classes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your class `public`. Without a modifier the default is `internal`, which is not "visible" enough for your purposes. See also [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).